# How to make new dataframe from existing dataframe with unique rows values of one column and corresponding row values from other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe **'raw'** that looks like this -
[image]

It has many rows with duplicate values in each column.
I want to make a new dataframe **'new_df'** which has unique **customer_code**  corresponding and **market_code**.
The new_df should look like this -
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you simply want to create a DataFrame with unique `customer_code` which also shows `market_code`. Here's a way to do it:

```py
df = df[['customer_code','market_code']].drop_duplicates('customer_code')
```

Output:

```
  customer_code market_code
0        Cus001     Mark001
1        Cus003     Mark003
3        Cus004     Mark003
4        Cus005     Mark004
```

The part reading `df[['customer_code','market_code']]` gives us a DataFrame containing only the two columns of interest, and the [`drop_duplicates('customer_code')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) part eliminates all but the first occurrence of duplicate values in the `customer_code` column (though you could instead keep the last occurrence of each duplicate by calling it using the `keep='last'` argument).

Comment: Sometimes you are so messed up even the simplest solution doesn't come to your mind. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Pandas is powerful and convenient, but its usage is far from self-evident, so I think we've all had that experience at one time or another.